# Excel vba EntireRow.AutoFit does not work

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following code in an add-in, which is called from the ribbon. It is meant to make all lines visible from the current line to the next visible line. The lines are hidden by an autofilter.

```
Sub Details4(control As IRibbonControl)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
    SendKeys "+{DOWN}+ ", True
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:" & Selection.Rows.Count).EntireRow.EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

It does mark the lines as i wanted it to do, but the auto-fit does not work. When I double-click the line-height (which should do the same as the autp-fit) alle lines are visible as I wished this do to.

Can anyone see a problem? I know "sendkey" is not the best Thing in programming, but I had no other easy idea how to mark the range up to the next visible line...

Thanks
max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by changing the code to:

```
For Each Row In ActiveCell.Rows("1:" & Selection.Rows.Count)
    Row.EntireRow.AutoFit
Next
```

and deleting the line

```
ActiveCell.Rows("1:" & Selection.Rows.Count).EntireRow.EntireRow.AutoFit
```

of course...

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra .EntireRow call.

```
   Rows("9:13").EntireRow.autofit
```

Works just fine.

For your sendkey issue, try something like this:

```
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Comment: thanks for your comments! the double "entireRow" is what Excel proposes when recording the macro; also remobing this makes no difference. Selection.End(xlDown) selectes the whole rest of the list, not just the next visible cell.

Comment: @Max  Wierd, I did a test of that exact autofit code and it performed as expected.  There must be something else restricting things.  Is the file you are using a new file, or one that has existed and been worked in a lot?

Comment: the file is new, i did dome tests too: if i hide the lines manually, the unhide works, also if they are hidden as Group. Only in an autofilter it does not work - although the autofit by double-clicking works.